# Undefined reference error in gcc using libnet

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program in gcc using the libnet library. I have the libnet.h file included in my code, but when I try to compile it, I receive an error message:

```
/tmp/ccTEOH93.o: In function `main':
random_name.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `libnet_init'
random_name.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `libnet_seed_prand'
random_name.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `libnet_get_prand'
random_name.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `libnet_get_prand'
random_name.c:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `libnet_name2addr4'
random_name.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `libnet_name2addr4'
random_name.c:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `libnet_hex_aton'
random_name.c:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `libnet_hex_aton'
random_name.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `libnet_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to compile it by manually including the libnet.h library or the libnet-functions.h library(which includes all the functions from above) when using the gcc. Still nothing worked. The compiler even send an error message saying that the library could not be located.

What do I do? What is the problem?

I tried to compile it by browsing to the file this program is stored in and then typing:

```
 gcc -o example example.c
```

or

```
 gcc -o example example.c -l libnet.h (or just libnet)
```

this has worked when compiling all my other programs and I can not see what is wrong. I even tried it by altering the order of my gcc input.

Comment: **How** are you trying to compile your program? unless we see that, how can we possibly know what is missing? I *suspect* you are either not linking the library (which is different from the header file) - or are linking it in the wrong order

Answer (score 2):

Header files and libraries are different things.

A header file (or *include file*) contains **declarations** of objects (specifying their type, size etc.). Header files are used during the compile phase of a build i.e. when converting source code into architecture-specific object code. The names of the headers to include are given in the source code itself rather than on the compiler command line, for example

```
#include <foo.h>
```

If a particular header file is not located on the compiler's standard search path, additional paths may be given on the command line e.g.

```
gcc -o myprog.o -c -I/path/to/foo myprog.c
```

Libraries on the other hand contain actual object **definitions** i.e. pre-compiled units that implement the object. These are used during the link phase (when your object files are linked with any dependent system libraries to form an executable program), and *are* specified on the command line, e.g.

```
 gcc -o myprog myprog.o -lfoo
```

Here, `-lfoo` tells the compiler to search for a library with the name `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so` (note that the leading `lib` is implied, and is omitted on the command line i.e. `-lfoo` rather than `-llibfoo`). Like with header files, non-standard library paths may be accommodated using option `-L` e.g.

```
 gcc -o myprog myprog.o -L/path/to/foolib -lfoo
```

In your case, assuming that both the header file and library are located where the compiler expects to find these things, and that you want to compile and link in a single command, you should probably use

```
gcc -o example example.c -lnet
```